# I can't create multiple instances of "Enemy" correctly Java

Tags: java

When I try and create more than one "Enemy" they stack atop one another and behave incorrectly. Ints enemyX and enemyY represent it's coordinates. I understand that they probably shouldn't be static but another class references them using Enemy.enemyX/Y. How can I create multiple "Enemies" and still give the class using Enemy.enemyX/Y the coordinates of each Enemy. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Enemy extends GameObject {

    public static int enemyX = 50;
    public static int enemyY = 360;
    public int enemyMoveX = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 5,
            enemyMoveY = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 5;
    public int angle;

    public void tick() {
        angle++;
        if (angle == 360) {
            angle = 0;
        }
        enemyX += enemyMoveX;
        enemyY += enemyMoveY;
        if (enemyX > 1250 || enemyX < 50) {
            enemyMoveX = -enemyMoveX;
        }
        if (enemyY > 670 || enemyY < 50) {
            enemyMoveY = -enemyMoveY;
        }
        enemyX = Main.clamp(enemyX, 0, Main.WIDTH - 32);
        enemyY = Main.clamp(enemyY, 0, Main.HEIGHT - 53);
    }

    static int sizeX = 30, sizeY = 30;
    Color randomColor = new Color(255, (int) (Math.random() * 125),
            (int) (Math.random() * 125), 255);

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.translate(enemyX + (sizeX / 2), enemyY + (sizeY / 2));
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(sizeX / -2, sizeY / -2, sizeX, sizeY));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Enemy` class is NOT an `enemy` object. When you say `Enemy.enemyX`, the code has no idea which `enemy` object you are referring to. You are right in thinking `enemyX` is not supposed to be static, because making it static turns it into a global variable, instead of an object member.

This is a sign that you have a problem at the code that uses the `enemy`, not in the `Enemy` class (after you make the member variables non-static anyhow).

Answer (score 0):

Hello to one of the reasons why you shouldn't use `static`

```
public static int enemyX = 50;
public static int enemyY = 360;
```

This means that EVERY instance of `Enemy` will have the EXACT some x/y value, all the time.

Also, if you're going to use `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();`, you should make sure to call `g2d.dispose();` when you no longer need it

Answer (score 0):

Simple, don't declare enemyX and enemyY as static variables.

```
public static int enemyX = 50;
public static int enemyY = 360;
```

should be:

```
private int enemyX = 50;
private int enemyY = 360;

public int getEnemyX() { return enemyX;}
public int getEnemyY() { return enemyY;}
```

To get the coordinates of each enemy,
iterate through your list/array of Enemy, and call `getEnemyX()` or `getEnemyY()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Enemy extends GameObject{

public static int enemyX;
public static int enemyY;
public int enemyMoveX = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 5,
        enemyMoveY = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 5;
public int angle;
```

Why not make it:

```
public class Enemy extends GameObject{

 private int enemyX;
 private int enemyY;
....
```

and then add two methods which can return the X and Y values to other classes/methods.

```
public int getEnemyX() {
 return enemyX;
}

public int getEnemyY() {
 return enemyY;
}
```

When you declared enemyX and enemyY as `static` it meant that ALL instances of the variables would be identical. By not making them static, each instance can take on its own value.

EDIT: You will also need a constructor to make each instance of the Enemy.

```
public Enemy(int xValue, int yValue) {
 enemyX = xValue;
 enemyY = yValue;
}
```

Comment: Lets say i'm in another class. How would I make an int = getEnemyX() sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: If you're in another class, let's say

`public class TestClass {`

and you need this class to access the `enemyX` and `enemyY` positions.

By making 

`public int getEnemyX {
  return enemyX
}`

Your other function can now call 
`int x = Enemy.getEnemyX();`

And now x will be the EnemyX value.

Comment: But doesn't that mean `getEnemyX()` would have to be static? Here's my error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getEnemyX() from the type Enemy`

Comment: Nope.

Are you sure your class is

`public class Enemy extends GameObject{

 private int enemyX;
 private int enemyY;
....`

enemyX and enemyY should not be static, and neither should the methods returning them.

Comment: This is how I'm trying to use those methods in the other class: `int trailX = Enemy.getEnemyX(), trailY = Enemy.getEnemyY();`  And here is my Enemy class: `public class Enemy extends GameObject{
 
 private int enemyX, enemyY;
 
 public Enemy(int xValue, int yValue){
   enemyX = xValue;
   enemyY = yValue;
 }
 
 public int getEnemyX(){
  return enemyX;
 }
 
 public int getEnemyY(){
  return enemyY;
 }`

Comment: The trailX and trailY are not being declared static, correct?

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure why it's not working. That's exactly what i originally tried before I even posted my original question... Probably something obvious I'm missing.